# Jqueryui autocomplete w/ Django - is there a way to autocomplete only after special characters?

Tags: django, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I don't think I've seen this done before, so I'm not sure how it might work.  I want to use jqueryui to get autocomplete values from my models - but only when a left parentheses character is typed.

Example:

Enter the name of a city, followed by its state in parentheses.

Albany(New York)

The source would be states

^ I'm looking for a way for New York to pop up, which would be an instance of a 'State' model, once "(" is entered and then "n".  I'm not even sure which part of the framework will reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem like this should help you.

This is based on the official [jqueryui autocomplete example](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default), I put a little comment on the most relevant parts:

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    // use only the string after "(" to compare against the example array. 
    response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, request.term.slice(request.term.indexOf("(") + 1)));
  },

  search: function( event, ui ) {
    var input = event.target.value;

    // don't trigger autocomplete until "(" is present.
    if(input.indexOf('(') !== -1) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  },

  select: function( event, ui ) {
    var input = event.target.value;

    // return the inputted string + selected value, instead of just selected value alone
    ui.item.value = [input.slice(0, input.indexOf("(") + 1), ui.item.label].join("");
  }
});
```